# OCR software with automatic translation

Tags: windows, ocr, translation

I'm looking for an application that will allow me to swiftly select a portion of my screen, (like the snipping tool does) preferably by hotkey, and then return me the text translated to English.

Does such a program exist? I've tried Capture2Text but that doesn't seem to do the translation part. Their method of capturing parts of my screen however is exactly what I'm looking for.

In my usecase I'd like to use such a program to quickly translate Mandarin text on my monitor (including but not limited to pictures and regular text) to English so that I can read Chinese webcomics more easily.